# Safely escape strings for SQL fragments for joins, limits, selects, and so on (not conditions) on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-injection, escaping

In Ruby on Rails, for conditions, it's easy to make SQL-injection-proof queries:

```
:conditions => ["title = ?", title]
```

where title comes from the outside, from a web form or something like that.

But what if you are using SQL fragments in other parts of the query, like:

```
:select => "\"#{title}\" AS title"   # I do have something like this in one instance
:joins => ["LEFT JOIN blah AS blah2 ON blah2.title = \"#{title}\""]
```

Is there a way to properly escape those strings?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Typically in Rails, joins are done as a symbol (or as a hash for second-order joins) representing an id join, and you use the conditions to filter it down. If you need to do it as shown, then you can use ActiveRecord's [`sanitize_sql_array`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002322) to clean a SQL string, like this:

```
sanitize_sql_array(["LEFT JOIN blah AS blah2 ON blah2.title = ?", @blah.title])
```

Comment: This is a protected method.

Comment: @FelipeZavan that's no longer the case for newer rails versions